# Can we take the coupling of $\mu$ and $\nu$?

Tags: probability, analysis

The author takes $X_1\sim Uniform[0,1]$ and $X_2=(X_1-0.5)^3$ for $f(x)=(x-0.5)^3$.

If $X\sim \mu$, then $\mu$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]$. But for $X_2\sim \nu$, is it a probability measure on $[0,1]$? It seems $\nu$ is a probability measure on $[-0.125,0.125]$.

Can we take the coupling of $\mu$ and $\nu$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both measures can be viewed as probability measures on the real line. Even if the support is not the same, a coupling of two probability measures on the real line does make sense.

Comment: Yes, I know that make sense. But I only want to consider the coupling on a compact set of $R^2$? How about this case?

Comment: Can we say the coupling $\pi$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]\times [-0.125,0.125]$?

Comment: Yes, it is a probability measure on $[0,1]\times [-0.125,0.125]$. I was not sure about what worries you in these kind of question if you know that it makes sense.

Comment: Also, this coupling of $(X_1, X_2)$ is called deterministic coupling? Since $Y=T(X)$, the coupling $\pi$ is concentrated on the graph of measurable function $T$. Also, $\pi=(Id, T)_{\#}\mu$?

Comment: How about some points in $[0,1]\times [-0.125,0.125]$ with zero probability mass? I mean the support of this coupling is not in $[0,1]\times [-0.125,0.125]$, right?

Comment: @Hermi The coupling $\pi$ defined as the probability distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ is concentrated on the points $\{(x, f(x)): x\in[0,1]\}$. Yes, $\pi = (\operatorname{Id}\times f)_\#\mu$. Indeed, $$\mathsf P((X_1, X_2)\in A) = \int_\Omega [(X_1, X_2)\in A]\,\mathrm d\mathsf P = \int_{\mathbb R} [(x,f(x))\in A] \,\mathrm d\mu = \mu(\{x\in\mathbb R: (x,f(x))\in A\})=(\operatorname{id}\times f)_\#\mu(A)$$ for all measurable $A\subset\mathbb R^2$. The support of $\pi$ is contained in the graph of $f$, which is contained in $[0,1]\times[-1/8,1/8]$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch So we can say $\pi$ is a probability measure defined on $[0,1]\times [-1/8, 1/8]$ or $[0,1]\times [-1,1]$? Or $[-1,1]^2$?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Does it matter if some points inside the $pi$ defined on $[-1,1]^2$ with no probability mass for a coupling?