# Probability density function and it’s value

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

The following question is there in a statistics textbook.
‘A petrol pump is supplied with petrol once a day. If its daily volume of sales $X$ in thousands of litres is distributed by $f(x)=5(1-x)^4, 0\leq x \leq1$
Is this correct? The pdf seems to be assuming values greater than $1$ for certain values of $x$.

Comment: The values taken by a PDF (probability density function and connected with continous distribution) are not probabilities (they are  required to be non-negative and can be larger than $1$). Things are different for a PMF (probability mass function and connected with discrete distribution).

Comment: Suppose the distribution had been uniform between $0.4$ and $0.5$ thousand litres.  Then the density would have been $f(x)=\frac{1}{0.5-0.4}=10, 0.4\le x\le 0.5$, but the probability of being in that interval would have been $1$ so everything would be OK

Answer (score 1):

CDFs take values between $0$ and $1$ but PDFs can take values larger than $1$. The given function is non-negative wand $\int_0^{1} 5(1-x)^4 dx=1$. So $f$ is a genuine PDF.

Comment: Can you help me see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500939/can-we-take-the-coupling-of-mu-and-nu? Thank you!